# Column widgets just stacks up instead of being scrollable

Tags: flutter, frontend, flutter-layout

Coding was going smoothly, but then when I add a couple of widgets to the body of my app. It was all displayed at the top of my screen instead of it lining downwards.

This is what it looks like:[image]

This is my code for the body:

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  appBar: buildEditProfilePageAppBar(),
  body: buildPageBody(),
  bottomNavigationBar: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.black54, blurRadius: 3)]),
    child: BottomAppBar(
      child: buildBottomBar(),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

This is my code for the compiling all the widgets:

```
     Widget buildPageBody() {
return Container(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
      buildImage(),
      SizedBox(height: 20),
      buildInfoText(),
      SizedBox(height: 10),
      buildDivider(),
      buildNameBox(),
      SizedBox(height: 7),
      buildEmailBox(),
      SizedBox(height: 7),
      buildMobileNumBox(),
      buildSecurityText(),
      SizedBox(height: 10),
      buildDivider(),
      SizedBox(height: 10),
      buildPassTextBox(),
      SizedBox(height: 10),
      buildInfoText(),
      SizedBox(height:10),
      buildDivider(),
      SizedBox(height: 10),
      buildCompanyBox(),
      SizedBox(height: 10),
      buildIndustryBox(),
      SizedBox(height: 10),
      buildWebsiteBox(),
      SizedBox(height: 10),
      buildBusinessEmailBox(),
      SizedBox(height: 10),
      buildCompanyMobileNumBox(),
      SizedBox(height: 10),
      buildBusinessAddressBox(),
    ])));
```

}

I think this is the problem

```
   Widget buildIndustryBox() {
return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
      left: 20,
      right: 20,
    ),
    child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
              padding:
                  EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10),
              child: Text('Industry',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black54,
                      fontSize: 15,
                      fontFamily: "Poppins"))),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 3),
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    ),
                    isDense: true,
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      fontFamily: "DMSans",
                    ),
                    hintText: '  ',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ]));
```

}

Comment: add code of the widgets that are in the top

Comment: @Fatimaayaa I just added the code, I think this specific widget messed it up and I dont know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column widget is not scrollable by itself. There are other widgets for that, such as ListView, CustomScrollView...etc. But however, if you want the column to be scrollable you can wrap it with another scrollable widget such as SingleChildScrollView, but still, that may not make the column scrollable if the view is large enough to contain the column. So if you want to make the SingleChildScrollView scrollable no matter the size, you can add `physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()` to the SingleChildScrollView and it will work.